# flash as3 sortOn - sorting an array by another array's position

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, sorting

I'm not quite sure how to do this - I'm building an admin interface to sort the order of a series of flash slides into a dynamic presentation. The admin interface pulls the slides from xml and displays each as a thumbnail. The thumbnails, when dragged, reorder themselves in the array appropriately. The problem is, I want the actual array of slides to reorganize itself accordingly. My code is this:

```
function onThumbPress( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    e.target.startDrag();
}

function onThumbRelease( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    sortSlides();
}

function sortSlides():void
{
    project_thumbs_array.sortOn( 'x', Array.NUMERIC );


    for (var i:int = 0; i < project_thumbs_array.length; i++) 
    {
        TweenMax.to( project_thumbs_array[i], 0.5, { x:(project_thumbs_array[i].width + thumb_spacing) * (i % thumb_cols), y:(project_thumbs_array[i].width + thumb_spacing) * int(i / thumb_cols), ease:Expo.easeInOut } );
    }

}
```

So what I want to do is take the change in the array (say 0 moves in front of 1 in project_thumbs_array) - and make sure that my other array (project_clips_array) moves item 0 in front of 1 as well. I thought something like this might work but it doesn't:

```
project_clips_array.sortOn ('project_thumbs_array.x',Array.NUMERIC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course keep two arrays and update or manipulate the second one to match the sorting of the first, but this is tedious and will get increasingly confusing, if you ever want to add more information to your slides (such as titles, captions, etc.) - you'd have to keep an array of titles, an array of captions, whatever, and do the same sorting for all of those.

It is cleaner (and gets better performance) to keep associative arrays (in AS, that's Objects) of all properties related to each slide inside a single sorting array, instead of having separate arrays for each property.

In my example below, each object in the array has properties x, y, thumb and slide. Tweens manipulate the numeric values x and y, and thumb positioning is updated when the values change.  Sorting is based on the numeric value x instead of the actual thumb position.

```
var project_array:Array = [];

//--- 
// Some code initializing the array here.
// Array elements should each look something like this:
var object:Object = { 
                      x: project_thumb.x, 
                      y: project_thumb.y, 
                      thumb: project_thumb,  
                      slide: project_slide 
                    }; 
//---

function sortSlides():void
{
    project_array.sortOn( 'x', Array.NUMERIC );

    for (var i:int = 0; i < project_array.length; i++) 
    {
        var obj:Object = project_array[i];
        TweenMax.to( obj, 0.5, 
            { 
              // tween numeric values instead of thumb position
              x:(obj.thumb.width + thumb_spacing) * (i % thumb_cols),
              y:(obj.thumb.width + thumb_spacing) * int(i / thumb_cols), 

              // update thumb position according to values
              onUpdate: function ( item:Object ) 
                        { 
                            item.thumb.x = item.x; 
                            item.thumb.y = item.y; 
                        }, 
              onUpdateParams:[obj], 
              ease:Expo.easeInOut 
            } );
    }
}

function onThumbRelease( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();

    // update sorting values after drag
    for ( var i:int = 0; i < project_array.length; i++) 
    {
        var obj:Object = project_array[i];
        obj.x = obj.thumb.x;
        obj.y = obj.thumb.y;
    }

    sortSlides();

    // call slide here:
    for ( i = 0; i < project_array.length; i++) 
    {
        obj = project_array[i];
        if (e.currentTarget == obj.thumb) 
        {
            doSomethingWithSlide (obj.slide);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great example, and probably a better way to structure things. In my project, there is really only one slide clip though - each time the user hits next, the clip retrieves the proper data from the new XML node. So there would only ever need to be two arrays - The array for the thumbnails for the organizer, and the overall number sequence. Initially, that array would be 1,2,3, etc, but as the thumbnails were rearrangedl, that new number sequence array might be 1,3,2 etc. I could structure it as in your example, but it'd be a lot of work, so I'm hoping to try and do it this way.

Comment: I would still strongly recommend to do it "my way" - it will save you time tenfold when looking for bugs and making things work coherently, just because you can actually read what is happening directly in the code.

Comment: I suppose you're right. Better late than never I guess. If I do it this way, how do I create arrays or perform functions within the object? For example, one of the properties of the object is an array: project_types : myXML.projects.project[i].@type.split(", "). So I want to say, within the object, for var i in project_types, switch (project_types_array[i]){}, but it doesn't seem to allow you to run functions within an object declaration. It also doesn't seem to allow you to create a property within the object that is blank (like a blank array that can be populated later)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  You can run a function within an object declaration: `var foo:Object = bar();` is perfectly legal. You can also assign an empty array: `foo.array = [];`  But this doesn't seem to be what you are really looking for.  If you want your objects to have behavior, you can always create a class ProjectData and make the array contain instances of that class, instead of simple objects.  The rest of the code would remain exactly the same.

Comment: so within the syntax of the example above, what would the empty array declaration look like? var slideObject:Object = { slide_Array : [] } doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, this does: `var obj:Object = { array:[] };` I can trace obj.array, I can use `obj.array.push(1,2,3);` etc.  So you must have something else wrong there.

Comment: I don't know - yeah - this whole method of doing this is really unfamiliar to me - I suppose I just need to spend some time with it. I just don't like the lack of the ability to just run functions within the object. If I declare a function inside the constructor, like bar() and then I run bar() outside of the object constructor, it loses all scope with the particular object being created. I don't want to keep wasting your time, but thanks a lot for your help though.

Comment: Like I said - just create a class instance instead of an object.  Classes can have all kinds of methods, and you can always use `this`.  There are ways of doing this with plain objects, as well, but using a class is certainly more simple and straight-forward.

Comment: hey - sorry to keep at it - but I restructured all of my code so that all properties are contained within an object, and all objects are contained within an array. I then added the thumbnails from each object in the array to the stage. But I still can't solve the initial problem - how to sort the array based on an attribute. I want to set it up so that if the thumbnail is dragged, the whole array sorts. I think the problem is that the thumbnail, by being added to a movie clip on the stage, no longer has a tie to the containing array, so the array cannot be sorted based on its x val.

Comment: I put my code online here if anyone wants to have a look: http://mikeheavers.com/transfers/presentation.as

Comment: Why don't you just copy the onThumbRelease() code I used?  It should update all x and y values before sorting...

Comment: hah - man - it's scary to me that you figured all that out in like ten minutes, and it took me all day to implement it. Reminds me of a scene in Goodwill Hunting. I'm so getting fired...

Comment: No, you're not.  You are willing to learn, and you *are* learning. That's a good thing. :)